# Change the order of IP addresses returned by ifconfig?

Tags: ubuntu, ip, ubuntu-10.04, ifconfig, chef

I have an Ubuntu server with several IP addresses attached to it.  127.0.0.1 is listed as venet0 by ifconfig.  I'm using [Chef](http://www.opscode.com/chef) to configure the server.  The problem is that chef is listing 127.0.0.1 as the IP address for the server instead of one of the server's "real" IPs. (apparent "ohai ipaddress" uses the first IP listed by ifconfig to determine the server's IP).

How can I change the order so the servers main IP is listed first instead of the 127.0.0.1?

Can venet0 be deleted and venet0:0 be "promoted" to take its place since 127.0.0.1 is already listed in the "lo" interface?

```
lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:334 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:334 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:16700 (16.7 KB)  TX bytes:16700 (16.7 KB)

venet0    Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  P-t-P:127.0.0.1  Bcast:0.0.0.0  Mask:255.255.255.255
          UP BROADCAST POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:7622207 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:8183436 errors:0 dropped:1 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:2102750761 (2.1 GB)  TX bytes:2795213667 (2.7 GB)

venet0:0  Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  
          inet addr:XXX.XXX.XXX.XX1  P-t-P:XXX.XXX.XXX.XX1  Bcast:0.0.0.0  Mask:255.255.255.255
          UP BROADCAST POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP  MTU:1500  Metric:1

venet0:1  Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  
          inet addr:XXX.XXX.XXX.XX2  P-t-P:XXX.XXX.XXX.XX2  Bcast:0.0.0.0  Mask:255.255.255.255
          UP BROADCAST POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP  MTU:1500  Metric:1
```

route -n

```
route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
192.0.2.1       0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 venet0
0.0.0.0         192.0.2.1       0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 venet0
```

Comment: The answer is probably not in the ordering of interfaces but the configuration of chef to use a specific interface rather than pick the first it finds.

Comment: At a first glance at the configuration I can't find anything mentioning the interface. Perhaps your server's hostname is set to localhost and so resolves to the loopback adapter? If so, a fix could be to change the hostname to a domain pointing to the external ip.

Comment: Almost certainly the issue isn't the order of interfaces but the order of *routes*.  What does `route -n` say?  Really, though, trying to make the loopback address be something other than localhost screams of "doing the wrong thing".  Why are you not using private IPs for your virtual network? (eg, 192.168.55.x to pick a random network)

Comment: @DerfK - I've added the results of route -n to my question.

Answer (score 4):

`ohai` uses `route` to find the "default interface" by finding your default gateway (destination 0.0.0.0):

```
network[:default_interface] = from("route -n \| grep -m 1 ^0.0.0.0 \| awk \'{print \$8\}\'")
```

(From [line 21 as of right now](https://github.com/opscode/ohai/blob/703afe89acbf915dc026119d41e1af1d39b918d0/lib/ohai/plugins/linux/network.rb))

The problem is that `route` doesn't care about the aliases on interfaces (`venet0:0` and `venet0:1` are aliases of the `venet0` interface), it assumes that anything sent through the aliases all goes out the same device, so it lists `venet0` as the outgoing interface.  This is logical when the interface is a physical interface, but when it's a virtual interface it could be wrong (and *is* wrong in this case).  Because of this behavior, it's also technically wrong for ohai to rely on it to determine the "correct" IP address to use, even if the base IP address wasn't 127.0.0.1.

The ideal fix is going to be for you to reconfigure your network settings so that the un-aliased venet0 interface is your "primary IP".  If you REALLY need venet0 to be 127.0.0.1 for some reason (I'm not familiar with the venet* interfaces so I don't know why you have it this way or what would happen if venet0 was the primary IP address instead of 127.0.0.1), then you might try finding that network.rb file (`/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/ohai/plugins/linux/network.rb` in [Lucid](http://packages.ubuntu.com/lucid/all/libohai-ruby1.8/filelist)) and editing it to read

```
network[:default_interface] = "venet0:0"
```

(or whichever interface you want it to report as the correct address).  I don't know if from() strips the newline that the command would print at the end so it might need to be `"venet0:0\n"` for ohai to work right.  Note that this will be replaced when you upgrade the package it was in.

I am personally curious as to whether `ip route list` (from the `iproute` package) shows your "default" route using the venet0 interface or venet0:0 interface.  Likewise, `netstat -r`.   If either shows venet0:0 then you might suggest in a bug report to ohai that they try those commands first and if they don't work, try again with the "normal" route command.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a way to do this, unless you just remove your loop back device. Not to be nosy, but why does it matter what order they are in?

Comment: Because Chef uses the first one it finds and stores it as the servers main IP.  This attribute is used in all kinds of configuration recipes...

Comment: Don't! Don't ever remove the loopback device.. This can break some seriously dark magic.

Comment: Tom: I already have a seperate device labeled lo for 127.0.0.1.  Is it necessary to also have the IP listed on the venet0 interface?  Seems redundant...

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to change things around by rearranging entries in `/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules`.

If you don't have any entries there, you can try adding your own. This is an example:

```
# PCI device 0xXXXX:0xXXXX (XXXX)
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="00:00:00:00:00:00", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="eth*", NAME="eth0"
```

Comment: Nothing is listed in that file on my system.

Comment: @erikcw: See my edited answer. The commented line would contain the PCI ID for the device (if it's PCI) and a short description. I believe the comment is optional.

Answer (score 0):

What I find bizarre and troubling is that you have the same IP address defined both on your lo and your virtual interface venet0.

My only guess as to why this would be setup this way is that you were unable to bring up the interface without an address though this could have been done with an IP of 0.0.0.0.

Removing the 127. address on venet0 would most likely resolve that problem as well as correct a potential security/performance hole ( fairly sure chef is smart enough not to grab your loopback address ).

Answer (score 0):

It may be nothing more than coincidence but it looks to me like it's being sorted alphanumerically by interface name. I see the same thing on my Linux boxes.

I know nothing about Chef but can you pipe the output of ifconfig through a script which will rearrange it into whatever order you do want?